# Node.js v4.4.3 DNS resolution not working as expected

Tags: node.js, dns

I have an application running on Oracle Linux 7 with Node.js v4.4.3.  Our server has two DNS servers defined in resolv.conf.  We Recently had the primary DNS server fail, so the secondary DNS server defined in resolv.conf should have worked.  But Node.js failed to use the secondary server.  It was almost as if it ignored the secondary and only tried to use the primary.

I thought it might have been an OS issue, so I manually modified the resolv.conf file and tested with DIG and it correctly used the secondary server, but when I tried with Node, it just wouldn't work.  I wrote the program below to do some testing, basically modifying the resolv.conf while the program ran and nothing.

```
"use strict";

var dns = require('dns');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var httpClient = require('request-promise');

//Initialize Express and Handlebars
var app = express();
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
//Configure express app settings
app.engine('handlebars', expressHandlebars({extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function(req,res){
  var options = { uri : 'https://someother/internal/api', json : true };
  httpClient(options)
    .then(function(data){
      var success = { data : data };
      console.log(dns.getServers(), 'Ok!');
      res.json(success);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      var failed = { error : err.message };
      console.log(dns.getServers(),err.message);
      res.status(400).json(failed);
    });
});

app.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log("app started");
});
```

Any thoughts on why Node wouldn't re-read the resolv.conf or why it would not use the secondary DNS server when it realized the first was not working is appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the secondary server after the node process had started?

Answer (score 0):

You have roughly 3 options.

1. Add more application servers if your app is stateless
2. Lower the timeout in resolv.conf to 1 with rotate if you have multiple dns servers
3. increase the number of processes equal to the number of logical cores

You could do all three. This is really just a performance issue.

Comment: my team just recently resolved this issue with only needing to do option 2 above
if we have more issues when dns servers go down we will have to look into adding app servers or start down the road of caching dns in node server based rest client calls with something like an axios interceptor

Answer (score -1):

Node.js doesn't use the system's DNS resolution

https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_implementation_considerations

Comment: this is false

It does use system dns resolution. The problem people are having is due to process limitations see article

https://medium.com/swlh/solving-node-dns-issues-and-other-things-5051d8526cac